# How can I transfer a logged in user's login data from one server to another?

Tags: php, webserver, authentication

I have one server "A" where users can login. Login is verified by an LDAP server "L".
I have a different server "B" were users can log in, too. Login is verified by the same LDAP server as before. Both servers are standard web servers with PHP.

My goal is: If a user is logged in to server "A", and if he clicks a link to log in to server "B", the user should automatically be logged in without re-entering username and password. What is a good and secure way to achieve this? I can't submit username and crypted password to server "B". I can't use the PHP session of server "A", because it does not exit on "B". Cookies won't work either.

I think that there is a way, but I just can't see it. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think this is more of a programming question and belongs on SO

Comment: Have you ruled out a shared session path?

Answer (score 0):

If your servers share a domain name (a.example.com and b.example.com) you can share the session cookie and use the same backend session store. We're currently using [memcached sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php#ini.memcache.session-handler) in our setup, but it's relatively easy to [write your own session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) against some other store like MySQL.

Barring that, use some sort of [centralized authentication server](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS) that allows distributed hosts to authenticate against a single authentication entry point.

Comment: The servers do not share a domain name. I will investigate your last link (CAS) and try to find out if this can help.